# remove_action not working for a function

Tags: hooks, actions

I want to remove specific function from `wp_footer` action. This is what I added in functions.php of my child theme.

```
remove_action( 'wp_footer', [ 'Fusion_JSON_LD', 'print_json' ], 999 );
```

In this line `print_json` is function name and `Fusion_JSON_LD` is the name of class. Priority is already higher than the `add_action` but I do not know why it is not working.

This is how this function was added in parent theme which I could not edit directly.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', [ $this, 'print_json' ], 110 );
```

I tried `after_setup_theme` action for this but even this one did not work.

Comment: The original hook uses `$this`, so to remove it you need to use the same instance of that class. So the original plugin needs to make that instance accessible in some way. If you search the plugin code for `new Fusion_JSON_LD` the you will be able to find where that instance is.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thank you for this suggestion. Class is declared in parent theme and I need to execute remove_action in child theme to remove one of its function.

Comment: Yes? I know, you explained that. You need to find out where the class instance is stored to be able to retrieve it. I can't help you with that based on what's in the question. You either need to search the theme code, or if you don't understand it, ask the theme author.